# How to get a UK visa refund

Tags: visas, uk, fees-and-charges

I applied online for a visa application to the UK. I'm from Sri Lanka. Yesterday I cancelled the appointment, I changed my mind. I will not go to the visa appointment. Now my question is how I get my refund?

Comment: When my sis-in-law applied to a UK Visa the papers/forms she had to fill said the VISA processing fee was non-refundable. No idea how it happens if you cancel it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro "Visa" is just an ordinary word. It shouldn't be written in all caps or even capitalized unless it's the first word of the sentence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you canceled **before carrying out your biometrics** then you will **get a refund.** You have to complete the visa refund form. Otherwise, **In any other case**, Visa fee is **non-refundable.**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [gov.uk site](https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa) has a whole page about this, the summary at the top states:

If you applied **outside the UK** [contact UKIV](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) to find out how to cancel your application

> You can only get your fee refunded if your application hasn’t been processed yet.

If you applied **within the UK** You can cancel via [an online form](https://eforms.homeoffice.gov.uk/outreach/Return_of_Documents.ofml), but you will not be refunded.

> You won’t get your fee refunded if you cancel an application that you
>   made in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Your fee (less any applicable admin fees) will be refunded to the card used to make the original payment.