# UK Visa Refund form after cancelling my application

Tags: visas, uk, refunds

I had a VISA Appointment and I cancelled it day before (I could not reschedule as its within 24 hours ) and claimed for refund.  I had to cancel as I have not received invite from from the concerned person as they are on holiday due to Christmas and new year.
On many other forum and other question like here [About UK visa fee refund](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117781/about-uk-visa-fee-refund) I see people have mentioned that a refund letter has to be filled and submitted but I did not see any such information when I cancelled my VISA application

My question is will I get a refund? and is the refund form mandatory, if yes how di I fill it?

Comment: It's the same situation as in the linked question as long as you haven't submitted your biometric data.

Comment: But my question is around VISa refund form. where to fill and submit it? I did not get any thing related to that while canceling my application

Comment: Did you contact the UKVI to cancel? https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get a refund but it may take up to 4 weeks.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Just quick question where should I fill refund form as I have not received any message from visa desk or UKVI to fill any form. I am thinking I do not have to fill any form.

Comment: @Anuj Kumar Jha contact them after 4 weeks if you still haven't received the refund.